# How to set all the item template data into a single view in Xamarin Carousel

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, carousel, itemtemplate

I have tried to make all the items in the itemtemplate into a single view as like in the below image, how to achieve this by using Xamarin CarouselView, i am using like this

```
        carousel = new CarouselView();
            carousel.BindingContext = this;
            carousel.ItemTemplate = itemTemplate;
            carousel.SetBinding(CarouselView.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding(nameof(this.Items), mode: BindingMode.OneWay));
   LinearItemsLayout linearItemsLayout = new LinearItemsLayout(ItemsLayoutOrientation.Horizontal);
            linearItemsLayout.SnapPointsAlignment = SnapPointsAlignment.Start;
            linearItemsLayout.SnapPointsType = SnapPointsType.Mandatory;
           carousel.ItemsLayout = linearItemsLayout;


 this.Children.Add(carousel,0,1);
```

[Expected UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4mee.jpg)

[image: But the Actual image is]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way of doing something like that would be to use the Horizontal [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#horizontal-list)

CollectionView can display its items in a horizontal list by setting its ItemsLayout property to HorizontalList:

When you check the documents it gives a similar example

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
            ItemsLayout="HorizontalList">
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Padding="10">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                <RowDefinition Height="35" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="140" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Grid.RowSpan="2"
                   Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"
                   Aspect="AspectFill"
                   HeightRequest="60"
                   WidthRequest="60" />
            <Label Grid.Column="1"
                   Text="{Binding Name}"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />
            <Label Grid.Row="1"
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   Text="{Binding Location}"
                   LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                   FontAttributes="Italic"
                   VerticalOptions="End" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

Alternatively, this layout can also be accomplished by setting the ItemsLayout property to a LinearItemsLayout object, specifying the Horizontal ItemsLayoutOrientation enumeration member as the Orientation property value:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}">
<CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" />
</CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
...
</CollectionView>
```

This results in a single row list, which grows horizontally as new items are added:

[image]

Comment: Freakyali, Is it possible to achieve by using CarouselView

Comment: CarouselView is experimental first of all so it has multiple bugs, secondly, the expected UI is not achievable using that since it can only show one item at a time, CollectionView, on the other hand, is easier to use and has the exact thing already available

Comment: a year later, is it advisable to use CarouselView for this type of UI? XF 5 has fixed several bugs

Comment: @Kronos CollectionView is still a viable solution. But you can choose what you like, More a matter of preference now